# Navigation without class="current"

Tags: jquery, html, css, menuitem, menubar

I suspect this must be a common practice, but I can't seem to search the right phrase. I'm looking to create a basic html/css navigation menu that styles the current page's button uniquely from the other buttons.

I could obviously use a class such as class="current" on the corresponding buttons. However, I'm hoping to only use one single snippet of code that could be dynamically loaded onto each page (preferably client-side) for easy edits in the future. Is there a common solution to this?

Thanks!

**Update: Example code**

```
Current Route:
http://www.example.com/homer.html


HTML

<body class=""> (class added with Javascript)

<ul>
<a href="homer.html"><li>Homer</li></a>
<a href="marge.html"><li>Marge</li></a>
<a href="bart.html"><li>Bart</li></a>
</ul>

</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daniel_studiolynch/9U6sS/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pattern I use.

Set a class on the body tag when the page loads. Use the current route (hash or otherwise).

```
// www.yoursite.com/#somehash
document.body.className = window.location.hash.slice(1); //somehash
```

Then in your css, use that class to determine an 'active' state.

```
.somehash .nav-btn.somehash{...}
```

Comment: Basically, you're adding a class to the body, and then you can write CSS rules that style each nav button as 'active' when it's a descendant of the right body class(es).

Comment: This seems like a very simple and elegant solution. I'm a Javascript noob, but I think I can swing this. Thank you to everyone for your help.

Comment: So in order for the default 'home' nav button to be selected, does the initial page request need to go to site.com/index.php#home ?

Comment: I just added some sample code up top. Would anyone mind showing a specific example? As I started experimenting with this method, I realized that I'm obviously missing something. @jcsanyi

Comment: Aha, I see now.  You have a css rule for each link. One extra step from what I was envisioning, but a very easy way to do it nonetheless. Definitely a time saver when working with lots of pages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I agree with this approach, but here it is since my other answer didn't quite make the cut.

```
// Grab Current URL
var thispage = window.location.href;

// Find where A.href == Window.href
var thisnav = $("a[href='" + thispage + "']");

// This doesnt need to add a class if you dont want to. 
// This is simply showing you how to identify the <a> tag that contains the current URL
thisnav.addClass("green");
```

and here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4Vff9/

Comment: This is actually a great way to do it too. I'm getting the basic concept here. Thanks David.